# Need a tag for general "physics" questions.

Tags: discussion, tags

[physics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) maybe?

- [What is negative voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/what-is-negative-voltage)
- [What is the skin effect?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7092/what-is-the-skin-effect)
- [Lightning bolt vs. batteries: a coulomb in everyday terms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10909/lightning-bolt-vs-batteries-a-coulomb-in-everyday-terms)

I see two various levels of this,

1. for questions that are independent of any electronic parts, for instance the above three, and
2. questions that are about how a given part works beyond ordinarily required practical knowledge (e.g. How do you make MOSFETs?,  What is the the intrinsic layer for in a PIN diode?),

The latter is still essentially a physics question, but would likely be in narrower areas, e.g. solid-state physics.

Comment: NickT, I understand your issue here, but we need a hard definition of what constitutes a physics question if we are going to make a tag and create a wiki for when to use it. What ideas do you have for this?

Comment: @kort, updated.

Answer (score 1):

I added a comment awhile back, but since community decided to bump this post I figured I would add an answer and maybe get this questions 'answered' to communities liking.

**About Physics on this site**

Purely physics questions are off-topic here, especially now that there is a [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). It is only in beta so we can't rely on the site being their long term, but even if there is no Physics.SE it is still off-topic here.

One of the questions you linked to has a comment of:

> You will do better to think about electronics as a kind of applied math, and forget about the electrons entirely. – markrages

That speaks a lot about our community and how we don't view things as strictly physics.

**What about those questions**

Although these *could* be physics questions, they are on-topic here as they are based strictly around electronics. The answers they get could be very different here compared to on Physics.SE with both being correct, just from different perspectives.

So what should these be tagged as? They may not be associated with a specific electronic part, but they are related to a specific topic, such as [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage) and [energy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy). I am perfectly fine with us continuing to use this method.